# How 8 bit memory access behaves when we replace replace the /dev/mem mapping with a normal memory allocation

Tags: c, memory

So, I was observing how execution time behaves for various bit word, below is example of a program that read 8 bits word. I wanted to check how it behaves when we replace the /dev/mem mapping with a 'normal' memory allocation (i.e by malloc/calloc). But my code started giving segmentation fault (Core dump). Any help?

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static uint32_t map_size = 0x08000000;
static uint32_t map_base = 0x18000000;
static uint32_t map_addr = 0x00000000;
static uint64_t cycle_count = 0x1000000;


static char *dev_mem = "/dev/mem";

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int fd;
uint8_t *buf;
if ((fd = open(dev_mem, O_RDWR | O_SYNC)) == -1) {
    printf("can't open /dev/mem .\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

buf = (uint8_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
if (buf == 0) {
    printf("Can't be mapped. \n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
} else
    map_addr = (long unsigned) buf;

uint8_t sum = 0;

while (cycle_count-- > 0)
    sum += *buf++;

printf("%u\n", sum);
close(fd);
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);


return 0;
  }
```

I am new to this, so sorry if the errors are silly.

Comment: are you trying to read the same word cycle_count times?

Comment: yes, I don't think that's the problem, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

sum += *buf++;

You are adding the value that buf points to into sum and then incrementing buf. So you are actually incrementing the address, not the value.
Just adding a parenthesis should fix the problem:

```
 sum += (*buf)++;
```

You should read more about the postfix increment operator and [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).